# pyinstaller. Как к приложению на Linux правильно приделать иконку в угол окна и в панель задач?

Tags: python, linux, pyinstaller, pysimplegui

Использую PySimpleGui + pyinstaller.

Сделал простенькое приложение из одного окошка для Linux, при закуске в углу окна и в панели задаx дефолтная иконка питона, как бы я не старался.

```
window = sg.Window('', layout, icon='gear.ico',
               titlebar_icon='gear.ico', #лежит в одном каталоге с главным скриптом
               background_color=strong_gray,
               keep_on_top=False
               )
```

Собираю такой командой:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon='./gear.ico' --add-data './gear.ico:.' main.py
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А пробовали команду -i, вместо --icon <https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-i>

Comment: Вот много ответов <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291113/pyinstaller-setting-icons-dont-change>

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение
icon= sg.EMOJI_BASE64_NO_SPEAK

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается Linux не использует файлы .ico для таких ситуаций, нужен .png.